# Does the generalized Hairy Ball Theorem hold for exotic spheres?

Tags: differential-topology

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Let $\langle M,\text{charts} \rangle$ be an $n$-dimensional $C^1$ manifold such that the

induced topological space is homeomorphic to the $n$-dimensional sphere.

Does it follow that ((all continuous vector fields on $\langle M,\text{charts} \rangle$ have a zero) if and only if ($n$ is even))?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the Poincare-Hopf Index Theorem. 

Comment: In particular, on an $n$-sphere (regardless of which differentiable structure it has) there is a vector field with precisely $|\chi(S^n)|$ zeros, each zero having index $1$, where $\chi(S^n)$ is the Euler characteristic of $S^n$, i.e. $0$ if $n$ odd and $2$ if $n$ even. 

Comment: Is there any citation for that theorem only using $C^1$-ness? Everything I've found for it either does not say what amount of differentiability is being assumed or does not even state that it must be a _differentiable_ manifold (which is necessary for the problem to even make sense).

Comment: If the manifold is $C^1$ it admits a compatible $C^\infty$ atlas.  Similarly, if you have a continuous vector field without zeros, you can smooth it to a $C^\infty$ vector field without zeros.   So I think the $C^0$ vector field case reduces directly to the $C^\infty$ case, provided the manifold admits any kind of smooth structure, like say a $C^1$ structure. 

Comment: Is that basically a folk theorem?  Do you know any reference for it?

Comment: No, it's not a folk theorem.  It's proven in many differential topology textbooks.  Hirsch's "Differential Topology" has all the proofs, for example. 